# How to compress a super big picture and not oom?

Tags: android, bitmap, image-compression

I have a image of 1080 × 49507, compression has OOM

```
Failed to allocate a 33554444 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 24MB until OOM
```

But I use wechat but it can be compressed normally, how does it work, is there any way to compress this big picture?

Comment: zlib allows you to compress via inflation/deflation parts of a file at a time.. so you don't need to load the entire thing into memory..

lz4 also supports chunked compression (this is what Unity3D supports as well). WeChat might be compressing to file and not to memory..

Comment: 1080 × 49507 ?  you can't do it with a large amount of size. In your case, you have 49507 px of the image height. Please make sure.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 choices 1 compress your image and you can do it using one of the following libraries

```
       https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor

       https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor

       https://github.com/shaohui10086/AdvancedLuban


       https://github.com/Sunzxyong/Tiny
```

or crop your image